# MIME type found and No video with supported format

Tags: java, html

```
<video width="320" height="240" controls loop>
    <source src="movie/Wildlife.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

I wrote this code but it's not working and shows no video with supported format and MIME type found. It's not working for any browser I've tested, including firefox version is 26.0, what should I change?

Answer (score 0):

Firefox does now have (at least partial) support for .MP4 files as of version 27.0 (which is now stable/public).

If you want to support earlier versions of Firefox, however, you'll need to use a different video file format, such as **.ogg**.

Answer (score -1):

[Firefox doesn't support .MP4 files.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Supported_media_formats) but i guess that [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15606797/no-video-with-supported-format-and-mime-type-found) would help.