# HTML5 video wont play

Tags: html, video, mp4, ogg, webm

HTML5 video wont play videos and I cannot play them directly from the server but they play in firefox and opera locally. I cant figure out what Im missing. Took this tag straight from w3c

```
<video width="500" height="300" controls>
  <source src="video.ogv" type="video/ogg">
  <source src="video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="video.webm" type="video/webm">
Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

ERROR is "No video with supported format and MIME type found"

EDIT: Error when accessing video directly in firefox is...

"Video playback aborted due to network error."

Comment: check the content type your sever is sending

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15606797/no-video-with-supported-format-and-mime-type-found

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following lines to your web-server's ".htaccess" file:

```
AddType video/mp4 mp4 m4v f4v f4p
AddType video/ogg ogv
AddType video/webm webm
AddType video/x-flv flv
```

This clears up supported format/MIME type issue.

Comment: I have this in my .htaccess, do I need to wrap it with anything?

Comment: problem was this is on windows server so I have to edit web.config not .htaccess.