# MIME type error in firefox mp4 video play

Tags: apache, .htaccess, firefox, mp4

I am trying to play video files in `Mozilla Firefox 29.0.1`. From the solution I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15606797/no-video-with-supported-format-and-mime-type-found), my html is :

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
</head>

<body>
<video width="320" height="240" controls>

  <source src="wordpress.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <!--<source src="movie.ogg" type="video/ogg"> -->
Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
</body>
</html>
```

And the `.htaccess` is :

```
# MIME types for Video
AddType video/mp4 mp4 m4v f4v f4p
AddType video/ogg ogv
AddType video/webm webm
AddType video/x-flv flv
```

But I am still getting the error `no video with supported format and mime type found` is displayed ! Whats wrong ?

Comment: At the time Firefox did not support playing mp4 files natively. This changed with FF 33 (I think), which shipped with the openh264 plugin from cisco.